# "Annotations are not allowed here" ao usar @Click no android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-activity

Estou começando a usar android annotations agora
Tenho a seguinte classe

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_login)
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @ViewById(R.id.senha)
    private EditText senha;

    @ViewById(R.id.usuario)
    private EditText usuario;

    @ViewById(R.id.button)
    private Button entrar;

    @ViewById(R.id.esqueceu_senha)
    private TextView esqueceu_senha;


    @Click(R.id.esqueceu_senha){
        void onClick(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EsqueceuSenha.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Estou recebendo um erro do android no evento de click com a mensagem "Annotations are not allowed here". Alguma ideia do que possa ser o erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está sobrando uma chaves ai nesse @Click, tenta assim:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_login)
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @ViewById(R.id.senha)
    private EditText senha;

    @ViewById(R.id.usuario)
    private EditText usuario;

    @ViewById(R.id.button)
    private Button entrar;

    @ViewById(R.id.esqueceu_senha)
    private TextView esqueceu_senha;


    @Click(R.id.esqueceu_senha)//retirei a que estava aqui
        void onClick(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EsqueceuSenha.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
       // e essa
}
```

Fonte: https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/ClickEvents

Exemplos da documentação:

```
@Click(R.id.myButton)
void myButtonWasClicked() {
    [...]
}

@Click
void anotherButton() {
    [...]
}

@Click
void yetAnotherButton(View clickedView) {
    [...]
}

@Click({R.id.myButton, R.id.myOtherButton})
void handlesTwoButtons() {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Resolveu!! Errinho besta... Obrigada!